# Limit of sequence with exponential and ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the limit
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(  1+e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)
> ^{\sqrt[n]{x_{n}y_{n}}}
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{n},
> \quad
> \forall n\geq1
> $$
>   with $S_{n}\rightarrow S,-2<S<-1,$ and $\left(  x_{n}\right)  ,\left(
> y_{n}\right)  $ are two sequence with positive terms such that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{nx_{n}}=x>0,
> \quad
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{y_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}y_{n}}=y>0.
> $$

---

My attempt is to use Stolz-Cesaro theorem and the following lemma: if
$x_{n}>0$ for all $n\geq1$ and $x_{n}/x_{n+1}\rightarrow x>0$, then
$x_{n}^{1/n}\rightarrow x$. First observe that $e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}%
}\rightarrow0$. Hence we get that%
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(  1+e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)
^{\sqrt[n]{x_{n}y_{n}}}  & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[  \left(
1+e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)  ^{\frac{1}{e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}}}\right]
^{\left(  e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)  \sqrt[n]{x_{n}y_{n}}}\\
& =e^{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}},
\end{align*}
where $a_{n}=\left(  e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)  \sqrt[n]{x_{n}y_{n}}%
,n\geq1$. Now I insert the data from hypothesis and I write%
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}  & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(  e^{S_{n}%
}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)  \sqrt[n]{x_{n}}\sqrt[n]{y_{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty
}\left(  e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right)  \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}\frac{y_{n}%
}{y_{n+1}}\\
& =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{S_{n}}\left(  1-e^{S_{n}-S_{n+1}}\right)
}{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{nx_{n}}{x_{n+1}}\frac{\sqrt{n}y_{n}}{y_{n+1}}\\
& =-x^{-1}y^{-1}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{S_{n}}}{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{e^{S_{n}%
-S_{n+1}}-1}{S_{n}-S_{n+1}}\left(  S_{n}-S_{n+1}\right)  \\
& =-x^{-1}y^{-1}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{S_{n}}\left(  S_{n}-S_{n+1}\right)
}{n\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align*}
Here it all end. Am I wrong with the above argument? How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace $\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}$ with $\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}$ because given limit is $\frac{x_{n}}{nx_{n+1}}$. You cannot replace $\sqrt[n]{y_{n}}$ for similar reason.

\begin{align}
a_{n}  
& =\left(e^{S_{n}}-e^{S_{n+1}}\right) \sqrt[n]{x_{n}}\sqrt[n]{y_{n}} \\
& =e^{S_{n+1}}\frac{\left(e^{S_{n}-S_{n+1}}-1\right)}{S_n-S_{n+1}}(S_n-S_{n+1})n\sqrt{n}\frac{ \sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\frac{\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n!}}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt[n]{\frac {x_{n}}{n!}}\sqrt[n]{\frac{y_{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}} \\
& \to e^S \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{e}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\cdot x\cdot y\\
& =\frac{1}{4}e^{S-\frac{3}{2}} x y
\end{align}
Following fact had been used:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$
$$(S_n-S_{n+1})n\sqrt{n}=\frac{n \sqrt{n}}{\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right) \sqrt{n+1} \left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)} \to\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\to e$$
$$\lim\sqrt[n]{\frac {x_{n}}{n!}}=\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{nx_n}$$
$$\lim\sqrt[n]{\frac {y_{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}}=\lim \frac{y_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}y_n}$$